# BCP To Copy Headers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I am using a stored procedure to populate a table with the data that I need.  I am then using BCP to copy the data to a `.csv` file.

This process works, the one thing it is missing is that BCP is not copying the field names into row1 and I do not see a way to set `Header=Yes`.

How can this syntax be amended to add the header row?

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp Test12.dbo.test out C:\testfolder\123.csv -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Using the [Stack Overflow Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355876/export-table-to-file-with-column-headers-column-names-using-the-bcp-utility-an) provided by Serg, I updated my syntax to:

```
Select @sql = 'bcp "Select ''abc1'', ''abc2'', ''abc3'', ''abc4'', ''abc5''
UNION ALL Select [abc1], [abc2], [abc3], [abc4],[abc5] from test" queryout "'
Set @sql = @sql + 'C:\testfolder\123.csv' + '" -c -t, -T -S '+@@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

However, this produces an error:

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

`abc3` is a *datetime* column. Should I convert it differently?  I did not have to provide any cast/convert when I used the initial syntax.

(I also tried to use `CAST([abc3] As Date)` but that threw the same error).

Comment: You can automate column list generation. Extract it from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, or merge bcp- produced template file with data. No single step solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `UNION` to include the column names is that column names are strings but the fields in the unioned query are not necessarily strings (as you discovered with that error posted in the Question). And you cannot convert names into other types such as `INT`, `DECIMAL`, `MONEY`, `DATETIME`, etc.

> I did not have to provide any cast/convert when I used the initial syntax.

That is because **BCP.exe** was converting each non-string field of the table (or result set) into a string so that it could be placed into the output file. But when you `UNION` two or more queries together, you need to ensure that each position within each `SELECT` matches that same position in all the other `SELECT`s so that a result set can be built.

Hence you are left with a few options:

1. Use `UNION` (similar to what you attempted), but then use `CONVERT` on the columns in the table that are not strings. For example (assuming that `abc1`, `abc3`, and `abc4` are `VARCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` while `acb2` is `DATETIME`, and `abc5` is `INT`):

   ```sql
   UNION ALL SELECT [abc1], CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), [abc2], 121), [abc3],
   [abc4], CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), [abc5]) FROM test
   ```

   The downside here is that you cannot use the simple syntax of just specifying the table name.
2. Create a text file of the header row as a separate step, then execute **BCP**, then concatenate the two files together. I show two examples of doing that in the following DBA.StackExchange answer: [Insert custom header row in BCP output](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125885/insert-custom-header-row-in-bcp-output/125913#125913)
3. Use .NET (SQLCLR or Console App; or PowerShell might even work) to execute the query and write the results to a text file. When using SqlCommand.ExecuteDataReader`to run the query, the returned`SqlDataReader` object will have the result set fields (names, datatypes, etc). You can use [GetSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx) to get the result set field info.

   If this seems like a good option but you either can't code this or don't have the time and/or desire to, I created a SQLCLR Stored Procedure that does exactly this, called **DB_BulkExport**, and is included in the Full version (this is not available in the Free version) of [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/). Sometime later this year there will be a stand-alone Console App version of this export, with additional features :-).

Comment: Great explanation.  I was going to recommend PowerShell as an easy end 'round.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli Thanks. Do you happen to know if it can also do the `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable` method? Does it have access to .NET stuff? Or just many of the same things named the same?

Comment: I haven't tried, but it has access to .NET methods and properties.  I'm not going to pretend to be a developer, not even on the hobbyist level.  So I'm not going to be able get much more detailed than that.  Another user that frequents these forums Shawn Melton, could probably answer that question in great detail.